# Export Data from mysql Workbench 6.0

Tags: database, export, mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to export my database, using MySQL Workbench 6.0 on Windows, to send to my db instance in Amazon RDS, but i'm getting this error:

```
Operation failed with exitcode 7
11:34:40 Dumping clubbin (taxicompanies)
Running: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe"
-defaults-extra- file="c:\users\selene\appdata\local\temp\tmp6o0hno.cnf"
--max_allowed_packet=1G --delayed-   insert=FALSE --host=localhost --user=root
--port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 "clubbin"   "taxicompanies"
mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'delayed-insert=FALSE'
```

Does anybody have any idea that can help me?

Answer (score 286):

> mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'delayed-insert=FALSE'

This error occurs on various systems and can be temporarily fixed by:

1. Going to the appropriate directory depending on the system:

   a) **Windows**: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules` (32-bit installation on x64 systems: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules`)

   b) **Mac OS X**: `Applications/MYSQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins` - right click on the app and select Show Package contents to get inside the app (thanks to [Bradley Flood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/958584/bradley-flood))

   c) **Linux Ubuntu**: `/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules` (thanks to [Alessandro Lopes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5537208/alessandro-lopes))
2. Open file `wb_admin_export_options.py`
3. Find line `"delayed-insert":["Write INSERT DELAYED statements rather than ...`
4. Insert `#` at the begin of this line to comment it out
5. Save file and restart Workbench.

Tested on Windows 7 x64, MySQL 5.6.27 (MyISAM) & Workbench 6.3.5 x64.

Tested on OSX Yosemite 10.10.4, MySQL 5.5.27 (MyISAM), Workbench 6.3.5 build 201 CE x64.

Comment: For users on OSX the `wb_admin_export_options.py` file is located in `Applications -> MYSQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins`. Note: right click on the app and select `Show Package contents` to get inside the app.

Comment: Fresh install of all new MySQL software on a new Mac with all updates as of Nov 1st, 2015. This fixes the export data issue. Thanks!

Comment: For Ubuntu users the is located at `/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_export_options.py`

Comment: INSERT DELAYED works only with MyISAM, MEMORY, ARCHIVE, and BLACKHOLE tables. For engines that do not support DELAYED, an error occurs. If you are using innodb comment this out

Comment: @cybermonkey - are you sure? I have tested workbench x32 on win32 and x64 on win64 - always installed in "Program Files" without "(x86)" in path...

Comment: @c4pricorn I meant 'installations of 32 bit Workbench' not '32 bit systems'- feel free to fix the edit.

Comment: Working tested on OSX 10.10.2 Yosemite and MySQL Workbench 6.3.5 build 205!

Comment: Gives access denied error :/ on win 8. my account has admin rights btw.

Comment: Just tested on my linux-mind 17.2 Rafaela and it's working!

Comment: Worked for me to. I even checked/unchecked the checkbox "insert-ignore - Write INSERT IGNORE statement rather than INSERT statements" in the data export options to no avail. The modification in the file worked perfectly on the other hand (DB MySQL 5.5.25 Community)

Comment: You should also delete the corresponding `.pyc` file, as workbench will still use this compiled file instead.

Comment: ON Windows 10, 64-bit and Workbench 8.0 CE, the file is located at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_export_options.py` on my machine.

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggested solution didn't help. Neither did unticking `tz-utc - Add SET TIME_ZONE='00:00' to the dump file` on the (Data Export) Advanced page. Everything was fine until I updated from Workbench CE 8.0.11 the the next release, 8.0.22. It wont work on MySQL5.6 or MySQL 5.7.28 database servers. :-(( WHY I HATE UPDATES. Only updated because a piece of their UI is broken, and in a moment of frustration (despite dealing with it for years...) I should know better than to update unless absolutely necessary. It probably overwrote a fix I had made years ago & took weeks to figure out

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me.

Edit the file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\wb_admin_export_options.py (make sure you open your editor as administrator)

find the line:

**delayed-insert":["Write INSERT DELAYED statements rather than INSERT statements.","FALSE", "BOOL", ("5.0.0", "5.7.0")],**

and put a hash “#” at the beginning of the line so that it looks like this:

**#    delayed-insert":["Write INSERT DELAYED statements rather than INSERT statements.","FALSE", "BOOL", ("5.0.0", "5.7.0")],**

This will comment the line out so that Workbench won’t use this statement.

Save and close the file.

Start Workbench and try again.

Reference http://dannytsang.co.uk/mysql-workbench-error-code-7/

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing it -- How is this different from c4pricorn's answer?

Comment: Agreed. The only difference is that a link was added, and explicitly indicated that Workbench should be restarted. But that link is 404, and the restart would better be left as a comment, not an new answer. This post should be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux Ubuntu/Mint:

The config file is located at :
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_export_options.py

As described by c4pricorn, simply comment the line "delayed-insert":["Write INSERT DELAYED statements rather than...

And restart workbench.

Answer (score 1):

Delayed inserts where deprecated in 5.6 and are converted to normal inserts in 5.7 (see also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-delayed.html). I wonder why mysqldump reports an error on this. Regardless, MySQL Workbench must be adjusted to no use `delayed-insert` for dumps. Can you please file a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com to bring this on the agenta for MySQL Workbench?

Comment: but they closed it as fixed. looks like they don't know what they are doing. Using the mysqldump from your mysql server 5.5 installation as they suggested would complain about a different unsupported parameter: `mysqldump: unknown variable 'set-gtid-purged=OFF'`

Comment: That bug is old (1.5 years old) and was about something totally different (which has been fixed). The issue asked about here is related to the new MySQL server (5.7.x). This problem has been fixed in MySQL Workbench 6.3.6.

Comment: Strange I was having the same bug with MySQL CE 5.5.46 and Workbench 6.3.5 just yesterday. Upgrading to 5.5.47 and 6.3.6 all seems fixed now. The delayed insert command-line option is only added when they are enabled. And mysqldump from the server installation is used by default. When the built-in mysqldump is used the option is invisible. yay, better than ever! Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

In CentOS 7,

Open file /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_export_options.py
Find line "delayed-insert":["Write INSERT DELAYED statements rather than ...
Insert # at the begin of this line to comment it out
Save file and restart Workbench.

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted at an earlier post, by putting a # at the delayed-insert line in wb_admin_export_options.py does solves the problem.What i like to add is that when i tried to edit it in notepad and Pythonwin,i encountered the admin rights issue.They don't let me save the file after my edit.I finally work around it by editing and saving it in notepad++.One can download it from here https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Answer (score 0):

Removing delayed-insert line in `wb_admin_export_options.py` solves the problem. You need to get admin rights to modify the file.

Nonetheless consider that your MySQL database might have been not properly upgraded before.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful on editor: on Win7 64 notepad doesn't work on this modification.
Notepad will present a single line, use an editor with crlf.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error until I upgraded to the latest version. Currently 8.0.15. That fixed it on my Mac.