# MySql Workbench 6 export fails with unknown variable '-internal-schemas=FALSE'

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql

When I try to export a schema to a self contained file I get the following error:

```
Running: mysqldump --defaults-file="/tmp/tmpJYzU44/extraparams.cnf"  
--$internal$show-internal-schemas=FALSE --host=localhost 
--protocol=tcp --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 
--single-transaction=TRUE --skip-triggers "myschema"

mysqldump: unknown variable '-internal-schemas=FALSE'
```

I have checked answers [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128223/export-data-from-mysql-workbench-6-0) and tried to comment out the following line in `/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_export_options.py`

```
"$internal$show-internal-schemas":["Show internal MySQL schemas (mysql, information_schema, performance_schema) in the export schema list.","FALSE"],
```

But when I restart Workbench I was not able to even view Data Export window. It gave me:

```
An unhandled exception occurred ('$internal$show-internal-schemas'). Please refer to the log files for details.
```

It seems that somehow Mysql Workbench produces wrong command line options for mysqldump. I could not find any settings to remove this infamous **-internal-schemas=FALSE** flag.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That other question also says that this bug was fixed in Workbench 6.3.6, so, upgrading to 6.3.6 should fix the problem.

Comment: No! Using 6.3.6 on Ubuntu 15.10 and it has the same bug.

Comment: @salihcenap I tried repeat your issue, but I can't. Can you please provide full debug log? Run Workbench with --log-level=debug3 command line argument, upload your log file to pastebin (or so) and paste link here.

Comment: Hi, running the program with --log-level=debug3 gave me nothing more. All I have is:
http://pastebin.com/7QVmeTxn

Comment: I wonder what "$internal$show-internal-schemas" is suppose to be converted to, perhaps into explicitly naming the internal schemas, such as sys? @salihcenap also what is your MySQL Server version that this is connecting to?

Comment: @salihcenap I'm sorry, I wasn't clear enough when I asked about your log file. What I meant was log file that you can find in menu Help->Show Log File.

Comment: @PhilipOlson "$internal$show-internal-schemas" is internal option and shouldn't be pass as argument to mysqldump, there is condition that filter it - it's mystery for me how could happen.